# How to use 'sendPoll' function in telegram BOT API

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I am trying to send automated polls (kind of a multiple choice question) on a Telegram Channel. But, the `sendPoll` function does not work.

Link: https://t.me/testwalachannel

I have tried sending test messages via API and it works.

Code snippet:

```php
<?php


$apiToken = "##### MY API KEY #####";

$data = [      'chat_id' => '@testwalachannel',   'message' => 'This is test message' ];

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
?>
```

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Similarly, I tried sending contacts and it worked. But, when I send polls with `sendPoll` method, it shows an error.

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll

Sample code:

```php
<?php


$apiToken = $apiToken = "##### MY API KEY #####";
$options =  array("Devendra","noneofthese","Sourabh") ;

$data = [      'chat_id' => '@testwalachannel',   'question' => 'This is whose number 12345 ?',  'options' => $options ];

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendPoll?" . http_build_query($data) );


?>
```

```php
<?php


$apiToken = $apiToken = "##### MY API KEY #####";
$options =  array("Devendra","noneofthese","Sourabh") ;

$data = [      'chat_id' => '@testwalachannel',   'question' => 'This is whose number 12345 ?',  'options' => $options ];

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendPoll?" . http_build_query($data) );


?>
```

Error response:

```json
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse options JSON object"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the issue.

I just needed to replace `'options'` => `json_encode($options)`